# Orbeon: set initial value for fields if a check box is checked

Tags: if-statement, xpath, checkbox, orbeon

I have multiple address fields: 
Street_number, Street_name, City, Country, State, Postal_code.
Suppose i filled those in the form previously

Suppose that later on in the form ***if*** I check a box, some of those previously filled fields concatenate into one address field

i am setting the "initial value" of this address field to the code below:

```
if($concat_checkbox=true())
then concat($Street_num, ' ', $Street_name, , ' ',$City,' ',$State,' ',  $Country,' ',$Postal_code)
```

Orbeon is complaining: "Incorrect XPath expression", what is the correct way to use conditions in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In XPath, you always need to have a `else` condition. In your case, I imagine that you're using the expression in a *Calculated Value*, so if the checkbox isn't checked, you just want to keep the current value, which you can do by adding `else .` at the end of your expression.

Also, to check on the value of the checkbox, I would recommend you use `$concat_checkbox/text() = 'true'`.

Comment: What i need is: if checkbox is checked, once filed, the field should be readonly including the values of the concatenated fields, if unchecked it should return to editable blank for the user to enter its own data.

`if ($concat_checkbox/text()='true')
then concat($Street_num, ' ', $Street_name, , ' ',$City,' ',$State,' ',  $Country,' ',$Postal_code)
else .`
I used the preceding code in calculated value.


in read only i used: `$concat_checkbox=true()`

when i test it, the  concatenated Address becomes grey (readonly), but the values of fields are not present.

Comment: For *Read-Only*, use `$concat_checkbox/text() = 'true'`. But this isn't why the concatenation doesn't work. When the form runs, can you check the `orbeon.log`? There might be a syntax error in the expression (say reference to non-existant field), that prevents the expression from running. Also, you can try simplifying the expression until it runs. (E.g. what if you put just `$Street_num` without the `if` or `concat()`; if that works, take it from there and make the expression more complex.)